# eliminate element from list vector

Tags: r, list, vector

I would delete element with length !=4 from this data structure

```
    library(partitions)
        permListParts <- function (x) 
        {
            f <- function(pp) {
                out <- split(seq_along(pp), pp)
                myPerms <- perms(length(out))
                apply(myPerms, 2, function(x) {
                    temp <- out[x]
                    class(temp) <- c(class(temp), "equivalence")
                    temp
                })
            }
            apply(setparts(x), 2, f)
        } 
  x=c(33,45,77,23,15)     
 parts <- permListParts(length(x))
            out <- rapply(parts, function(ii) x[ii], how="replace")
```

for delete i use this code:

```
for(i in 1:length(out)){
if(length(out[[i]][[1]])!=4){out=out[-i]}}
```

but cycle doesn't delete element that i would like

Comment: What if you try `for(i in 1:length(out))`? Your current specification of the loop runs only once, where `i` takes the value of `length(out)` and that's it.

Comment: Hello, please keep the [tag:rstudio] tag for issues clearly concerning the Rstudio interface. Cheers

Comment: Try `out[vapply(out,function(x) length(x[[1]])==4,TRUE)]`.

Comment: @bobbel, i forgot to write  1:length(out) here , but the result doesn't change